# PHP/CI3 - Type Casting Not Working As Expected with Boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am keeping all of my website settings in a table called mh_settings.  The mh_setting table has 2 fields, namely, name varchar(255) and type varchar(255).

In my MY_Controller.php in the core folder and in the constructor,  I read the name and key into config_item() as follows:

```
    $appConfigOptions = $this->MH_settings_model->mh_get_configurations();

    if($appConfigOptions) {

        foreach($appConfigOptions as $appConfigOption)
            {
            $this->config->set_item($appConfigOption->key,$appConfigOption->value);
            }

    }
```

The model gets the config items as follows:

```
 class MH_settings_model extends CI_Model {

 protected $table;

 public function __construct() {
            $this->table = 'mh_settings';
 }

 public function mh_get_configurations() {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->result();
 }

 }
```

For some reason, even if I type cast mh_site_up_public with a value in the data base of FALSE, it seems it is always making it a string.

```
    if(((boolean) $this->config->item('mh_site_up_public')) ==  FALSE) {
        show_error($this->config->item('mh_site_down_public_message'));
    }
```

I tried (bool) instead of (boolean).

I tried playing around with == and ===

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual value of `mh_site_up_public`? If it is a string that says `FALSE`, then it's truthy. Only empty strings (or a string with `0`) are falsy and will be cast as actual `false`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/7t5dc

Comment: In the database, it is FALSE.  When I echo $this->config_item('mh_site_up_public'); in the view, I also get FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table column is a varchar, `mh_site_up_public` will be a string with the literal text `FALSE`.
Non-empty strings (or if they only contains "0") will be considered true.

Example:

```
var_dump((bool) '');
// false

var_dump((bool) '0');
// false

var_dump((bool) 'any other content, including FALSE');
// true
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aD0QY

You can read more about it in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) about booleans.

Comment: I was hoping I would type case TRUE and FALSE from string to Boolean.  I changed the table entry to 0 and type casted that as Magnus Eriksson suggested and it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

String "FALSE" is not the same thing as boolean FALSE.

A string that contains *anything* evaluates to TRUE, so type casting is working as expected.

You can either change your fields to use INT (0 for false, 1 for true), in which case you may change your code to:

```
if(!$this->config->item('mh_site_up_public')) {
    show_error($this->config->item('mh_site_down_public_message'));
}
```

Or, if you choose to stay with VARCHAR, you will have to change your code to

```
if($this->config->item('mh_site_up_public') === 'FALSE') {
    show_error($this->config->item('mh_site_down_public_message'));
}
```